# How to copy a resolved git merge to another branch

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have feature branches `fb1` and `fb2`.

A team member merged them into a new `qa-branch-1`.
`fb1` had pretty extensive merge conflicts.
In QA, we found some issues with `fb2`, and he deleted `qa-branch-1`.

He asked me to redo the merge conflict resolution.

I still have my local copy of `qa-branch-1`, so is there any way to copy over the merge from there onto a new branch `qa-branch-2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `cherry-pick` to "pass" commits between branches.

```
// Cherry pick single commits (using spaces between commits)
git cherry-pick <sha-1> <sha-1>

// Cherry pick range of commits (using 2 dots betwen the commits)
// cherry-pick <first sha-1>..<last-sha-1>
git cherry-pick <sha-1> <sha-1>
```

Comment: I think this requires a `-m` flag for merge commits.

Comment: Might if you have commits. the `-m` are indexed from 1 and not from 0